# a.out remains the same when I compile a different file

Tags: compiling, gcc

I have 3 files in an instance of ubuntu. Compiling the first file went well with an **a.out** being created but when I try compiling the other files the output remains the same. Is it possible to compile and run different files in the same instance?
For clarification, **hello.c** is what **a.out** returns atm but I'd like to compile and run the other files.

```
ubuntu@lab1:~$ ./a.out
x = 1
y = 2
=====
x = 2
y = 1
ubuntu@lab1:~$ gcc 4.c
ubuntu@lab1:~$ ./a.out
x = 1
y = 2
=====
x = 2
y = 1
ubuntu@lab1:~$ ls
4.c  Mini-övning.c  a.out  hello.c
ubuntu@lab1:~$
```

After using **-o** I've seperated them but they still return the same output.

```
ubuntu@lab1:~$ gcc p1.c -o p1
ubuntu@lab1:~$ ./p1
x = 1
y = 2
=====
x = 2
y = 1
ubuntu@lab1:~$ ./a.out
x = 1
y = 2
=====
x = 2
y = 1
ubuntu@lab1:~$
```

Comment: See `man gcc`: use `-o outfile`

Comment: @Jos It worked in seperating them but it still has the same output :/

Comment: So... what is the output of `diff -s hello.c p1.c` ?

Comment: @steeldriver Identical......... oh wow, I copy + pasted the Path when I Transfered the files but forgot to change the Path to the correct file. Sorry and thank you!

Comment: Yoi have to  work out why the two source files are identical, and fix that, then everything should work as expected.

Comment: @SorenA Yeah I just figured it out, thanks!